# How to write a Trigger that executes when date_returned column is updated?

Tags: oracle, triggers

This trigger executes when date_returned column is updated. The trigger is supposed to calculate the fines and update the borrowers’ outstanding fines in the borrower table. The fine is $5 for each late day.

My tables:

```
DROP TABLE Loan_Transaction;
DROP TABLE Borrower;

CREATE TABLE Borrower ( 
Borr_ID          NUMBER (4) PRIMARY KEY, 
borr_name        VARCHAR2 (25) not null, 
borr_address     VARCHAR2 (50) not null, 
borr_city        VARCHAR2 (15) not null, 
phone            VARCHAR2 (8), 
borr_type        VARCHAR2 (2), 
books_on_loan    NUMBER(1), 
outstanding_fines     NUMBER (6,2), 
check (borr_type in('R','NR','S')), 
check (books_on_loan <10)
); 

CREATE TABLE Loan_Transaction ( 
loan_ID                 NUMBER (9) PRIMARY KEY, 
Borr_ID                 NUMBER (7) REFERENCES Borrower, 
Item_Copy_ID            NUMBER (7), 
loan_type               VARCHAR2 (1), 
loan_date               DATE, 
due_date                DATE, 
date_returned           DATE, 
check (loan_type in('O','R'))
);
```

What I have so far...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER fines
BEFORE UPDATE ON Loan_Transaction
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE fine_amt NUMBER;
BEGIN
SET fine_amt = (loan_date - date_returned) * 5
UPDATE Borrower b
SET outstanding_fines = (outstanding_fines + fine_amt);
END;
/
```

This is error: ORA-24344: success with compilation error

Answer (score 1):

Your code have syntax errors. Once you run the script to create trigger, you need to run sho errors to list the errors.

This line is invalid `SET fine_amt = (loan_date - date_returned) * 5`

Instead it should be `fine_amt := (:NEW.loan_date - :NEW.date_returned) * 5;`
Also your update statement does not make any sense. You need to have where clause to update only row related to the loan updated in loan_transaction table. This code is incorrect and also seems to be buggy.

You need to learn syntax and implement accordingly. Also you need to use :OLD, :NEW to refer the columns from loan_transaction in trigger.